# How to improve SQL query in Spark when updating table? ('NOT IN' in subquery)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Dataframe in Spark which is registered as a table called `A` and has `1 billion` records and 10 columns. First column (ID) is Primary Key.
Also have another Dataframe which is registered as a table called `B` and has `10,000` records and 10 columns (same columns as table A, first column (ID) is Primary Key).

Records in Table B are 'Update records'. So I need to update all 10,000 records in table A with records in table B.

I tried first with this SQL query:

`select * from A where ID not in (select ID from B)` and then to Union that with table B.
 Approach is ok but first query (`select * from A where ID not in (select ID from B)`) is extremly slow (hours on moderate cluster).

Then I tried to speed up first query with LEFT JOIN:
`select A.* from A left join B on (A.ID = B.ID ) where B.ID is null`

That approach seems fine logically but it takes WAY to much memory for Spark containers 
(`YARN for exceeding memory limits.  5.6 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memory`)..

What would be a better/faster/less memory consumption approach?

Comment: you can `broadcast` the smaller data frame to all the workers.

Comment: Can you please show an example with above case (or close to above example)?

Comment: Can it be achieved the same with AutoBroadcast? 
`conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", 1024*1024*200)`
or is the approach you are proposing different?

Comment: (1) - I'd suggest using a full join instead of not in + union. (2) Try to broadcast the small table when joining. (3) You can find here some hints for [Spark SQL Performance Tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html) and [Tuning Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html).

Comment: What is the size of second table? Do you need all columns of the 2nd table for this operation? Is data evenly distributed based on id column? What is the data format?

Comment: ID is Integer - 10 digits, 10,000 rows. Other table is 1 billion records.

Comment: Why are you finding all record in A that is not in B, as opposed to all records in A that needs to be updated?

Comment: `as opposed to all records in A that needs to be updated` and then what? There is no `update` option in Spark.

Comment: @Joe Thank you. I was curious, I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `left join` too rather than `not in`.

A couple of advices to reduce memory requirement and performance -

1. Please see the large table is uniformly distributed by join key (ID). If not then some tasks will be heavily burdened and some lightly busy. This will cause serious slowness. Please do a `groupBy ID and count` to measure this.
2. If the join key is naturally skewed then add more columns to the join condition keeping the result same. More columns may increase the chance to shuffle data uniformly. This is little hard to achieve.
3. Memory demand depends on - number of parallel tasks running, volume of data per task being executed in an executor. Reducing either or both will reduce memory pressure and obviously run slower but that is better than crashing. I would reduce the volume of data per task by creating more partitions on the data. Say you have 10 partitions for 1B rows then make it 200 to reduce the volume per task. Use `repartition` on table A. Don't create too many partitions because that will cause inefficiency, 10K partitions may be a bad idea.
4. There are some parameters to be tweaked which is [explained here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html).
5. The small table having 10K rows should be automatically broadcasted because its small. If not you can increase the broadcast limit and apply broadcast hint.

Comment: Hi, IDs are all unique.. Not sure for 1) how to measure count and group by since all will be = 1. Also should I try `repartition` as first part of query or?

Comment: If id is unique then not much can be done on 1st point. Repartition before hand and set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to say500

Comment: did any of the tip help? Specially the partition idea? If so you might want add some reps

Comment: I tried with repartitioning and did not help much.. still too long or out of memory..

Comment: But I switched back to Dataframe way of doing things and that helped..

Comment: Please see job stats which appears on port 4040 for standalone cluster. It will tell exactly how much data is consumes per task, gc time and memory per task. Partitioning helped me a lot to reduce memory pressure